# Delay function executes too quickly

Tags: arduino-mega

I'm making a hydroponics system that collects data and sends it to the user through a SIM module. The problem is that while I want it to happen only once every 15 minutes and for the pump to operate for 30 seconds only, yet the device seems to do everything 10 times as quickly, if not even faster. Is there any way to fix this without multiplying everything by 10?

````
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <OneWire.h> 
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <GravityTDS.h>
#include <Servo.h>

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 5
#define DHTPIN 7     
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define TdsSensorPin A1
#define PUMPPIN 11

SoftwareSerial mySerial(9, 10);
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
GravityTDS gravityTds;
Servo myservo;

char msg;
char call;

void setup()
{

  dht.begin();
  
  sensors.begin();
  
  gravityTds.setPin(A1);
  gravityTds.setAref(5.0);
  gravityTds.setAdcRange(1024);
  gravityTds.begin();
  
  myservo.attach(PUMPPIN);
}

void loop()
{  
  const unsigned long SECOND = 1000;
  const unsigned long MINUTE = 60*SECOND;
  const unsigned long HOUR = 60*MINUTE;
   
  delay(30*SECOND);
  int h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  float tdsValue = 0;
  float temperature = t;
  gravityTds.setTemperature(temperature);  
  gravityTds.update(); 
  tdsValue = gravityTds.getTdsValue();  
    
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); 

  
  
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
  delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+************\"\r"); // Replace x with mobile number
  mySerial.print(h);// The SMS text you want to send
  mySerial.print("% humidity, ");
  mySerial.print(t);
  mySerial.print(" degrees Celsius air temperature, ");
  mySerial.print(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));
  mySerial.print(" degrees Celsius water temperature, ");
  mySerial.print(tdsValue,0);
  mySerial.print(" ppm");
  

  
  delay(100);
  mySerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
  delay(1000);

  myservo.write(0);   //Clockwise maximum speed rotation
    delay(30*SECOND);
  myservo.write(90);  
  delay(15*MINUTE);


}```
````

Comment: Can you please verify the problem with the blink example, while nothing is connected to the Arduino? Just to narrow down the problem more. Maybe the fuses of your Mega are configured the wrong way. If the same problem happens with the blink sketch you could try using another Arduino to burn the bootloader via ISP. That also sets the fuses.

Comment: I wouldn't use delay with so long values. Check the current time using millis() instead. This will also allow you to keep the board responding (i.e. to button presses).

Comment: An unrecommended method it to change long SECOND = 1000; to long SECOND = 10000;

Comment: @Gil, how should it work?

Comment: Each "SECOND" will be 10X longer. Remember when you are in delay the computer can do nothing else.

Comment: @Gil, are you serious? do you understand the cause of the problem in the question?

Comment: He stated things are happening about 10X what he wanted, he asked for the easiest way and did not want to change the code which would be the best. I also stated that was unrecommended. What did I miss, he originally stated he did not want to change his code, this was the simplest way I saw at the time.  What did I miss?

Comment: you missed that 15*MINUTE is calculated as int and overflows so the result is a much shorter delay